# to get/set iscroll4 bar location

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, iscroll4

I am using iscroll4 plugin for android 2.3(with cordova.2.1.0) app development. By default, the scroll-bar always appears at the top. How can i change the location, say to the middle or anywhere according to the height i give such that the visible content also changes. I am using iscroll4 like this(in javascript in index.html):

```
 if(myScroll)
 {               
     myScroll.destroy();
 }

 myScroll = new iScroll('home' , { vScroll: true});
```

Here 'home' is the div where scroll is applied(contains 'ul' and 'li's).
Similarly, when i scroll down, how can i get the scroll height (ie. how much i scrolled down) in javascript. So, basically i am asking two questions viz. how to get the scroll height and how to set it with iscroll4.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the .js source file for iScroll, there is a method, I think scrollTo, which sets the scroll position, there must be a method to get it, if not, i guess it can be created in the file.

Comment: scrollTo is the method to set the location. How can i get the location ? If u can help me how i can create the get function, i will be really grateful. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it's some properties on the myScroll object.